# How can i use a field from 3th model for Domain?

Tags: odoo, odoo-13, odoo-14, odoo-15, odoo-16

Lets Create a Demo for question !

```
class Characters(models.Model):
    _name = "santex.characters" 
    ​licensor_brand = fields.Many2one("santex.licensor_brands", 
    ​domain="????????????????") # todo 


class LicensorBrands(models.Model):
    _name = "santex.licensor_brands"


    ​licensor_brands = fields.Many2one("res.partner", string="Licensor")


class LicenseContracts(models.Model):
    _name = "santex.license_contracts"

    licensor_contracts = fields.Many2one("res.partner")
```

Here is my question:
For licensor_brand field i need a Domain. This domain should be  match "licensor_brands" from "santex.licensor_brands" to
"licensor_contracts" from "santex.license_contracts".

Dummuy-Domain: [(santex.licanse_contracts.licensor_contracts), = ,(santex.licensor_brands.licensor_brands)]

THANKS FOR TAKING YOUR TIME !!!

i tried this [(santex.licanse_contracts.licensor_contracts), = ,(santex.licensor_brands.licensor_brands)] but it didn't worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a computed field to filter out licensor brands that are not referenced from licensor contracts and use the domain in the view

***Example:***

- 1. *Define the computed field*

```
def compute_partner_ids(self):
    self.partner_ids = self.env["santex.license_contracts"].search([]).licensor_contracts

partner_ids = fields.Many2many("res.partner", compute='compute_partner_ids')
licensor_brand = fields.Many2one("santex.licensor_brands")
```

- 2. Set the domain attribute on the field tag

```
<field name="partner_ids" invisible="1"/>

<field name="licensor_brand" domain="[('licensor_brands', 'in', partner_ids)]"/>
```